# Should I use from or in?

Tags: grammar

> He was participating in every community **from** which he wasn't banned
> yet.

I am wondering if you should use from, in or something else. I am not sure if it's grammatical or not.

Comment: You have both "in" and "from" in your sentence. Could you please clarify what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: _from_ is more likely to be used here and sounds more correct. _from_ is referring to the place in the community.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with applying both "in" and "from" here. The position of prepositions is often flexible. In this case, it would also be fine as *He was participating in every community which he wasn't banned **from** yet.*

Answer (score 0):

The construction "preposition+ which" occurs often because of certain set phrases. In you example, the set phrase is "ban sb from sth/from doing sth".

As to the reason why the proposition is placed before relative pronoun "which" is more of habitual reason, which means it is uncommon to position a preposition at the end of a sentence.